# Perturbations to a matrix causing drastic changes to matrix inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, inverse

I'm reading [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-241j-dynamic-systems-and-control-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_241JS11_chap04.pdf) article about matrix norms because I want to understanding the math behind SVD.

One of the interesting issues it brings up quite soon is the effect of perturbations to a matrix on its inverse.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    100 & 100 \\
 100.1 & 100\
\end{bmatrix}\\
A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -5 & 5 \\
 5.01 & -5\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$

And the perturbed matrix of $A$, $\Delta A$ and its inverse.

$$
\Delta A = \begin{bmatrix}
 100 & 100\\
 100.2 & 100\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
(\Delta A)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
 -10 & 10\\
 10.01 & -10\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

A minor change to the original matrix drastically alters the resulting inverse.

I'm interested in a formal approach to describing how the inverse of a matrix is affected by perturbations to the original matrix, i.e. how to describe $\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A_{ij}}$.

Does this have something to do with Jacobians?

**Edit**: taking advice from @Doug M, I plotted $det(\Delta A)$ over perturbations to $A_{2,1}$ over the interval $]0,5]$ of distance 0.1. As seen in the graph, with smaller perturbations the determinant is larger, but as the perturbations get larger, the determinant approaches 0[image]

Comment: $(A^{-1})_{22}$ is missing.

Comment: If $det(A)$ is near 0, then small perturbations in A will lead to drastic changes in A^{-1}.  In your example $det(A) = -10$ which doesn't seem that small, but it is pretty small compared to the size of the vectors in A.  Perhaps it would be better to say that $\partial det(A)/\partial A_{ij}$ is large.